# Installing PHP Pear without user prompt

Tags: php, automation, pear

Is there a command line argument that allows you to install PHP Pear without user prompt? I'd like to automate the following execution:

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php go-pear.phar
pear config-set preferred_state beta
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
rm go-pear.phar
```

**php go-pear.phar** prompts the user for install/configuration information.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but can you put those commands into a shell script?

Comment: Yes, but php go-pear.phar prompts you to choose install directory

Comment: Oh, ok... thought I'd throw it out there anyway :)

Comment: If you don't find another way, maybe [expect](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/119333) can help you to automate the user input? [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out [expect](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/119333) did the trick. Here is what I ended up with:

install-pear.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn wget -O /tmp/go-pear.phar http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
expect eof

spawn php /tmp/go-pear.phar

expect "1-11, 'all' or Enter to continue:"
send "\r"
expect eof

spawn rm /tmp/go-pear.phar
```

install-phpunit.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./install-pear.sh
pear config-set preferred_state beta
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

To run:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
chmod 744 ./install-pear.sh
chmod 744 ./install-phpunit.sh
sudo ./install-phpunit.sh
```

Comment: I submitted an update the script to take into account waiting for spawned processes to terminate, otherwise expect gets ahead of itself  and terminates before the install or files have been downloaded

Comment: doesn't work for me. still stuck at the prompting screen.

Answer (score 1):

`go-pear.phar` itself does not accept any parameters via CLI and thus cannot be run without user interaction (except when using input tools like `expect`)

When the phar is executed, the file [go-pear-phar.php](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/pear-core/trunk/go-pear-phar.php?view=markup) is run, which in turn starts [PEAR/Start/CLI.php](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/pear-core/trunk/PEAR/Start/CLI.php?view=markup). As you see, `getInstallLocations` does wait for active user input without a way to skip it.